# Setting a target or multiplefile for a grunt task with sass and autoprefixer?

Tags: node.js, sass, gruntjs, autoprefixer

I'm setting a grunt file for a task. My goal is to create a css file from a sass file (scss) and add an autoprefix to all the proprieties which require so. Initially I used the propriety multifiles but it didn't work, so now I'm using the target propriety that works fine, but my problem is, even if I target the very same file, it will create another file in my folder where I put all my sass files.

So far my file is the following:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({

        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        sass: {
            dev: {
                options: {
                    style: 'expanded',
                    sourcemap: 'none',
                },
                files: {
                    '../style.css': 'scss/style.scss'
                }
            },
            dist: {
                options: {
                    style: 'compressed',
                    sourcemap: 'none',
                },
                files: {
                    '../style-min.css': 'scss/style.scss'
                }
            }
        },
        autoprefixer: {
            options: {
                browsers: ['last 6 versions']
            },
            target: {
                expand: true,
                flatten: true,
                src: '../style.css',
                dest: ''
            }
        },
        watch: {
            css: {
                files: '**/*.scss',
                tasks: ['sass', 'autoprefixer']
            }
        },
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-autoprefixer');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);
}
```

My goal is to set up a global task for all my css files, like so:

```
target: {
    expand: true,
    flatten: true,
    src: '*.css',
    dest: ''
}
```

but it is not working even if I try something like:

```
target: {
        expand: true,
        flatten: true,
        src: '../*.css',
        dest: ''
    }
```

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `cwd` (stands for current working directory) which is the path where grunt looks for the files matching the pattern in `src`. Also define the `dest` so that it would create the destination file in the same folder.

```
target: {
    expand: true,
    flatten: true,
    cwd: '../',
    src: [ '**/*.css' ],
    dest: '../'
}
```

Comment: It works! Do you know where I can find this kind of documentation? The version that I found is totally different and it uses the pipe function

Comment: See this https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks. Everything has been clearly explained here.